# Multiple read more or less link using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add several read more links. As you can see, giving the same `ID` is forbidden and not working. can you please help achieving the result bellow using different way? I'd like to use this function on several block text on the website...

```js
document.getElementById("read_more").addEventListener( 'click' , changeClass);

function changeClass() {
    var content = document.getElementById("extra_content");
    var btn = document.getElementById("read_more");
    content.classList.toggle('show');
    
    if (content.classList.contains("show")) {
            btn.innerHTML = "Show Less";
        } else {
            btn.innerHTML = "Show More";
        }
}
```

```css
@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .extra_content {
    display: none;
  }
  #read_more {
    display: block;
  }
}

.read_more  {
  display: none;
}

.show {
   display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>here is some content.</p>
    <p id="extra_content" class="extra_content">here is some extra content</p>
    <button id="read_more" class="read_more">Show More</button>
     <p>here is some content.</p>
    <p id="extra_content" class="extra_content">here is some extra content</p>
    <button id="read_more" class="read_more">Show More</button>
</div>
```

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 2):

First of all let explain the reason why you cannot use the same identifier for different elements. So please read below as the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) states:

> The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

So one possible solution is to find elements by `name` or by `class` attribute. And toggle classes based on those. Find the example below:

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('read_more');

const onButtonClick = (event) => {
  const button = event.target;
  const dataTarget = button.getAttribute('data-target');
  const extraContent = document.getElementById(dataTarget);
  button.innerHTML = button.innerHTML === 'Show Less' ? 'Show More' : 'Show Less';
  extraContent.classList.toggle('show');
}

const attachingEvent = e => e.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);

Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, attachingEvent);
```

```css
.extra_content  {
  display: none;
}

.show {
   display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>here is some content.</p>
    <p id="firstTarget" class="extra_content">here is some extra content</p>
    <button class="read_more" data-target="firstTarget">Show More</button>
    <p>here is some content.</p>
    <p id="secondTarget" class="extra_content">here is some extra content</p>
    <button class="read_more" data-target="secondTarget">Show More</button>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: this solution is working well ! but then i'll have to create a target-data for each read more link ( the website i'm working on will have a lot of them, at least 30). i thought maybe there's a better solution like attributing the same class or name to all of my read more links?!  thanks again

Comment: At some point you need to somehow differentiate them, right? Just to choose which one to open. I mean I guess you need to show more information separately once you click on one specific button, not like opening all at once, no matter which button you click.

Comment: each button has its own text that has to appear... if i use the same target twice it works but then it shows the same text...